# run two usb midi controllers on same time?

Tags: key, midi, digital-piano, midi-controller-keyboard, octave

I have no experience with midi  but i have two devices (alesis v49 and akai pro mpk25) in total 74 key so is it possible to combine these to two midi work as one device to cover most of piano key ?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your software and there might be some tricky configuration, but the short answer is **yes**. For example, you can definitely do this in Apple Mainstage and Ableton Live.

Comment: Including using two smaller keyboards as one larger keyboard to play the same instrument?

Comment: @YourUncleBob Yes, that’s what I understand the question is about and that’s what my answer is about.

Comment: yes that was my question , to play same instrument but different octave or part of it

Answer (score 0):

There are possibly at least a couple ways to do this,

1. Transpose the Akai Pro MPK25 **up** using the octave key so that it
   will play the registers that the (untransposed) Alesis is currently
   playing
2. Transpose the Akai Pro in your software DAW, again by whatever
   amount of octaves it takes to allow the Akai Pro to play the 
   registers that the Alesis isn't

*For instance Alesis will play from C1 to C5 and Akai C# upwards*